# Tab content not loading on browser start or undo-close tab

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, tabs

When I undo a closed tab using the TabMixPlus addon, it does, indeed undo the tab, but the tab opens blank instead of loading it's content.

I've searched all through about:config for a setting and can't find it.

Anyone know how to get it to load the content?

I also have the same problem when I start Firefox - the session does not load the tabs, either.

Comment: You are missing essential information in your question, like your OS version and your Firefox version :/

Comment: Ah, you're right; sorry.  I'm running Waterfox 56.02 on Windows 7.  But I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to Water 55.1.01 and now everything works.  Something broke in one of the later versions.